# @Published Realm object not triggering view redrawing in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, observable, realm

In our app we use a `UserService` that is a `ObservableObject` and passed as environment. A synced realm is opened and the app user (a RealmObject) is obtained using flexible sync.

When updating the users properties, such as his username, the view does not get redrawn. This is against my expectations since `UserService` contains a `@Published` property where the user (that is being edited) is stored. On the database it clearly shows the property being edited, however the view does not get redrawn, only when restarting the app the new properties are shown.

What would be the best way to have a `UserService` objects taking care of all user related logic (storing a user object (reference to it), containing functions to update, ...) and use this to display the **active** data of this user throughout the views?

Here is a MRE (the login logic is left out to reduce complexity):

```swift
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift

class UserService2: ObservableObject {
    
    var realm: Realm
    @Published var ownUser: User

    var userNotificationToken: NotificationToken?
    
    init(realm: Realm, ownUser: User) {
        self.realm = realm
        self.ownUser = ownUser

        userNotificationToken = ownUser.observe { change in
            print(change) // just to see that the user object is actually live and being updated...
        }
    }
    
    func changeName(newName: String) {
        do {
            try self.realm.write {
                self.ownUser.userName = newName
            }
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
    }
}
struct TestView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var userService: UserService2
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(userService.ownUser.userName ?? "no name")
            Button {
                userService.changeName(newName: Date().description)
            } label: {
                Text("change name")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var realm: Realm? = nil
    
    init() {
        let flexSyncConfig = app.currentUser!.flexibleSyncConfiguration(initialSubscriptions: { subs in
            subs.append(
                QuerySubscription<User>(name: "ownUserQuery") {
                    $0._id == "123"
                })
        })
        do {
            let realm = try Realm(configuration: flexSyncConfig)
            self.realm = realm
        } catch {
            print("sth went wrong")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        if let realm = realm, let ownUser = realm.objects(User.self).where( { $0._id == "123" } ).first {
            TestView()
                .environmentObject(UserService2(realm: realm, ownUser: ownUser))
        } else {
            ProgressView()
        }
    }
}
```

The `User` Object looks like this

```swift
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class User: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id = UUID().uuidString
    @Persisted var userName: String?
    
    convenience init(_id: String? = nil, userName: String? = nil) {
        self.init()
        if let _id = _id {
            self._id = _id
        }
        self.userName = userName
    }
}
```

P.S. I assume I could observe changes on the object using realm and somehow force a view refresh, but I would find it much more clean using the already existing way to watch for changes and redraw views when needed using `@Published`...

P.P.S. This user object is created on the server using a trigger when someone authenticates. However, I assume this is not really relevant to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the usage of a reference type as "Source of truth".

`ObservableObject` and SwiftUI Views use Combine Publishers to know when to refresh.

The `@Published` value sends the `.objectWillChange` publisher of the `ObservableObject` only when its wrapped value "changes". "changes" in this context means it gets replaced. So value types are preferred here, because if you change one of the properties the whole object will be replaced. This does not happen for reference types.

Multiple possible solutions here:

- change the `User` class to a struct (Probably not wanted here, because this object implements Realm)
- use the `.objectWillChange.send()` method yourself before altering the user
- instead of altering the `ownUser`var replace it with a new one that contains the new information.

---

```
func changeName(newName: String) {
    do {
        self.objectWillChange.send() //add this
        try self.realm.write {
            self.ownUser.userName = newName
        }
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try this now. So using `self.objectWillChange` I can remove the `@Published` from the User property right? I guess this never really served its purpose anyways. Out of curiosity: why is `self.objectWillChange` called *before* aftually changing the object? how does Swift know when to actually redraw the view, since it therefore cannot be at the point of calling `self.objectWillChange`?

Comment: And one more thing: from how I understood it, SwiftUI only redraws the subviews that actually access the data that changed. This benefit is lost when calling `self.objectWillChange` manually, since everything using any data from the `UserService` would get redrawn. Is this correct? If so, is it not an issue?

Comment: Can `self.objectWillChange` be used without `.send()`? Your implementation gives me the warning *"Expression of type 'ObservableObjectPublisher' is unused"*

Comment: @D.Kee sorry there is a typo. It should of course read `self.objectWillChange.send()`. You "should" call it before it changes as the name implies "WillChange". I remember reading that somewhere but cannot find the source for that right now. But putting it right after a change works to. The implementation behind this is saddly only known to Apple. On the question of ommiting the `@Published`, if you plan to handle all changes to this object yourself you can safely remove it. It would still do something if your replace the `User` with a new one.